# How to label levels in R?

Tags: r

How do you try to label levels in R? For example there is a coloumn titled 'Smoke' that shows 1 for smoking and 0 for non-smoking. I want to label 1 as smoking and 0 as non-smoking. How do I label it within the coloumn? Please help out

I want to use the set_labels() fucntion. Howevevr it is not working. I think I am getting the package it is stored in wrong. Can anyone suggest the right package or any other way to answer the question above?